# Start terminal in ubuntu with a python script?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, python

How can I start a terminal in Ubuntu 16.04 with a python script, execute commands on that terminal, and retrieve the output from those commands?

For example, I want to check the contents of a folder (through CLI) and return the results to the python script. So, I want my python code to do this:

1. Open terminal
2. `cd <path/to/folder>`
3. `ls`
4. //Retrieve the output and process this information.

Is it possible to run CLI commands and listen to the results (because, the next command is based on the output of the previous command) without opening a terminal?

Comment: Do you just need the output, or you need the terminal to run?

Comment: Probably through a judicious use of `subprocess`.

Comment: I want to start an application which can be possible only through the terminal. So, I need the terminal to run and need the outputs as well.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Your question is very unclear as is. You need to specify more details.

Comment: Do do that, you don't need the terminal *at all*.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I edited the question with more content. Please check.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Can you provide me with some documentation on how this can be achieved?

Comment: In your case, you just need the `os` module. This has the advantage of being portable across different OSes, not just Linux. See https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html.

Comment: also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730964/python-script-execute-commands-in-terminal

Comment: @Marcellinov Note that `subprocess` is preferred to `os.system`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system.

Comment: thank yoy @edwinksl - yes, indeed in that answer there is a small discussion on `subprocess`. I would definitely opt for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a terminal, you're probably going to have to drum up a pty and connect stdin and stdout to it, then use the Subprocess module to run your application.  Even that won't filter out any curses escape sequences or ASCII graphics (why else would you need a terminal?) but if the app is checking for the presence of a terminal, it would work.

If all you need to do is run a command-line application and redirect its input and output, just use the Subprocess module directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `os` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
output = os.listdir('path_to_folder')  # output is a list
# Do whatever you want to output
```

You can read more about what else the `os` module can do at https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html. Note that the methods in the module are portable across different OSes, so you can in fact use your script outside Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess,shlex
command = 'ls -la'
workingdirectory = 'C:users/Account/Desktop'
try:
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, cwd=workingdirectory)

    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

     if stderr.decode('utf-8') == "":
         print(stdout.decode('utf-8'))
     else:
         print(stderr.decode('utf-8'))
```

https://github.com/chefsoftwarehouse/CMD.py/blob/master/CMD.py